# Local Variables to Global Variables within a function

Tags: python

Simple question.
How do I convert local variables within a function to global variables? Here is my code, for example, within my function I have three main if statements, the last one is not view able because I shortened the code on the website basically, if I were to select 1 as my choice, I would complete the section, then I would press 2. It would immediately say "local variable 'key' referenced before assignment". Thanks in advance.

```
def start():
    print("Welcome to the Encryption / Decryption program!\n-------------------------------------------")
    print("Please select a number (1-3) corresponding to the instruction you would like")
    menuInput = input("[1] Encrypt a message\n[2] Decrypt a message\n[3] Exit the program\n\n-------------------------------------------\n")

    if menuInput == '1':
        print("You have chosen to Encrypt a message!")
        invalid_input = False
        encrypt = input("Please type in the name of the file containing the non-encrypted message\n")
        encrypt = encrypt.upper()
        message = open("sample.txt","r")
        msg = ''

        for words in message:
            msg += str(words)

        if encrypt == "SAMPLE":
            key = ''
            for i in range(0,8):
                random_number = (random.randint(33,126))
                key+=str(chr(random_number))
            print(key)
            print("You will need this key to decrypt your file!")
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print("Encrypting your file now...")
            time.sleep(5)

    elif menuInput == '2':
        print("You have chosen to decrypt a message!")
        invalid_input = False

        print(key)
```

Obviously I will be calling different variables, I am just using the variable 'key' to make it easier to understand. Also, if anybody has any tips on writing to files and renaming files within python itself, it would also be a huge help due to me being fairly new to python so yeah! Thank you so much for your help I really do appreciate it!

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not call a function (and use a parameter) instead?

Comment: I'm not that good! haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
key = None

def start():
    global key
    # and so on...
```

However using global variables is not recommended. You should consider other options, as suggested in the comments. Anyway, if you're just starting with Python it's enough by now, there will be time for writing better code!

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your response! Do you know any good tutorials for python programming? I started this language about 1 and a half years ago so... :D

Comment: @Matt I'm afraid I couldn't recommend any english stuff since it's not my first language. However, read as much as you can! Every little thing is useful. There's no limit for the knowledge ;)